# Explain why encode method returns empty Vector

Tags: scala

I am expecting this code to return `Seq(List(a,2), List((a,2),(e,1)), List((a,2),(e,1),(t,1)))`, but it returns an empty `Vector`:

```
val ws: List[(Char,Int)] = List((a,2), (e,1), (t,1))

def encode(ws: List[(Char,Int)]): Seq[List[(Char,Int)]] =
  for {
    split <- (1 to ws.length)
    wst <- ws.take(split)
    wdt <- encode(ws.drop(split))
  } yield wst::wdt
```

Why does this return an empty `Vector`? When I try the statement `wst <- ws.take(split)` alone, the result is `List((a,2))`.

Comment: It doesn't return anything. Even if you fix 'a', 'e', 't', it still crashes with the glorious `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Please update your question with exact code which causing problem

Comment: Method parameter is named wsi2, but used inside is ws(3 times). Did you know that you can run your code in the REPL before posting?

Comment: what is the use of `wsi2` variable in function param ?

Comment: typo error. parameter should be ws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fast one liner that produces the desired output**

What you actually want seems to be:

```
println(ws.inits.toList.reverse.tail)
// output:
// List(List((a,2)), List((a,2), (e,1)), List((a,2), (e,1), (t,1)))
```

---

**Why empty Vector?**

In one way or another, the length of the argument `ws` decreases during the recursive call (because you drop at least one element before invoking `encode` recursively).

Once the length of `ws` has reached zero, the `ws.take`-generator becomes empty, so your `for`-expression becomes 
essentially

```
(1 to someNumber).flatMap(_ => Nil)
```

Since the `Range` produces a `Vector` after mapping / flatMapping, you obtain an empty `Vector()`, that is then returned.

---

**Long recursive solution**

If you (for whatever reason) insist on using recursion, you can do something like this:

```
val ws: List[(Char,Int)] = List(('a',2), ('e',1), ('t',1))

def encode(ws: List[(Char,Int)]): Seq[List[(Char,Int)]] =
  if (ws.isEmpty) {
    Nil
  } else {
    encode(ws.dropRight(1)) ++ List(ws)
  }

println(encode(ws))
// output:
// List(List((a,2)), List((a,2), (e,1)), List((a,2), (e,1), (t,1)))
```

That's what proper recursion should usually look like: you deal with the `Nil`-case and with the nonempty-list case separately, instead of relying on strange `flatMap`s that run out of stuff to iterate on.

Note that this solution is not terribly efficient, it would probably be better to create a helper method and reverse the input.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is helpful to understand the program logic.